# ipython notebook shortcut for close help window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ipython, jupyter-notebook

One of the nice things about ipython notebook is cell magic and shortcuts.
A very useful feature is that I can use <kbd>tab</kbd> for autocomplete and <kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> for a documented tooltip. Sometimes

I want to read more documentation though and for that I can use the `?`.

For example, if I type the following code into a cell,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv?
```

then a wonderful popup appears that can help me out.

[image]

The downside is that I need the mouse to close this helper tab by clicking on the `x` button that has been circled in the picture.

Is there a shortcut known for this? I love the functionality but I find that using the mouse to click and close the window slows me down when I am in 'the zone'.

I couldn't find it listed in the list of shortcuts either (which is accesible by first going to command mode <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and then accessing the help <kbd>h</kbd>), so I am not sure if this feature is currently supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IPython master/3.0 (Have to check on 2.x), go to command mode then press `q`. `esc` might work in some cases. I don't think there are shortcut in edit mode, but you can also bind your own shortcuts in recent versions.

Comment: The help shortcut on master does  say that in command mode `Q` and `Esc` close pager.

Comment: I had an older version of the notebook installed locally. I am now able to close the window. Thanks!